# Finding convergence of Series using Comparison Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Determine the Convergence of
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sin \left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$
Can i compare it to
$$  \left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \geq  n\sin \left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$
and since $\left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $ it is a p-series with p>1 then it is convergent and the smaller series also converges
I'm not sure though how to prove that the original is smaller then $\left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $

Comment: The inequality $\left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \geq  n\sin \left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$ is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x\in(0,\pi/2)$,
$$\sin x<x.$$
So $\sin \frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{n^3}$, and hence
$$0<n\sin \frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{n^2}.$$
Take $p=2$ of $p-$series will work.

And also you can use  Limit Comparison Test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\sin \left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^2}}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin \left (\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^3}}=1>0.$$

Comment: And for all $x$ real, $0 \leqslant |\sin x | \leqslant |x|$, so you don't even have to check if it is a strict inequality of a number smaller than $\pi/2$

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in this case we only need to get $\sin \frac{1}{n^3}<\frac{1}{n^3}$ because $\frac{1}{n^3}\in(0,1]\subset (0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Of course. It is just I'm a lazy mathematician so I don't like strict inequality and fact checking to match them. But your proof works perfectly.

Comment: $\sin x=x\iff x=0.$

Comment: Thank you Dldier, It is nice to meet you.

Comment: oh I think I understand thank you very much !